# Apps posting to Social Media

Tags: account, social-media

As a developer, I wish to create an app that has the ability to post to social media sites.
Best Practices: Should I create a new account (e.g. Not my own) on those social media sites I wish my app to be able to post to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should create new accounts on each site. You might want to avoid getting your original accounts flagged for suspicious activity.